# How to avoid bad behavior zooming to areas outside the data range

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've added zooming out to a highcharts application I'm working on, but I've noticed some really bad behavior when zooming back in. If the zoom window includes an area outside the data range of the graph, the resulting zoom level incorrectly ignores that area. Sorry if this is a bit unclear, I'm not certain how to explain it best.

Here's a fiddle showcasing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/rnAEB/

```
$(function () {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: "container",
            zoomType: "xy"
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Try zooming outside the data range'
        },

        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br />',
            pointFormat: 'x = {point.x}, y = {point.y}'
        },

        series: [{            
            data: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512],
            pointStart: 1
        }]
    });

    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(-10, 20, true);
    chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(-500, 1000, true);
});
```

Try zooming in to a rectangle from (5, 1000) to (10, -500). The resulting zoom area is around (5, 600) to (10, -100)... this is clearly not what the zoom request asked for.

I've tried hooking into the setExtremes event for the axis, and the bounds when this issue occurs are undefined. I can't figure out how to 'hijack' the setExtremes request to fix the undefined value however. I also cannot recursively call setExtremes from within that event.

Is this intended behavior? I can see why you would only want to zoom where data was - but I'd really like the freedom to zoom to locations where there isn't data for the sake of perspective.

Answer (score 3):

It appears this is intended behavior. Poking around in the highcharts source led me to the Highcharts.Axis.prototype.zoom method which has the following conditional:

```
    // Prevent pinch zooming out of range
    if (!this.allowZoomOutside) {
        if (newMin <= this.dataMin) {
            newMin = UNDEFINED;
        }
        if (newMax >= this.dataMax) {
            newMax = UNDEFINED;
        }
    }
```

I've tried setting the 'allowZoomOutside' option using the configuration options, but unfortunately there's no undocumented hook for it that I can figure out (or find in the source).

According to comments in the source, the zoom method is intended to be overridable (they mention stock charts specifically), and I'd rather avoid trying to manually set the 'allowZoomOutside' from outside and hoping it doesn't get wiped by some internal mechanism. Overriding with a version lacking this check works like a charm. Here's an updated fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/7XHMz/

If anyone can figure out how to properly set the 'allowZoomOutside' option though that's probably going to be the nicest way to do this.

Comment: Try this: `$.each(chart.yAxis, function (i, axis) { axis.allowZoomOutside = true; });`

Answer (score 0):

It is related with fact that "started chart" is generated in the own form (min/max values in both axss), then you call setExtrems, which is only event, called one time. So chart cannot "remember" new extremes. So you can define min/max values with numbers form setExtremes, and about events.

http://jsfiddle.net/rnAEB/1/

```
 xAxis:{
            min:-10,
            max:20
        },
        yAxis:{
            min:-500,
            max:1000
        },
```

Comment: This is a good way to think about it given its behavior. I'd like to dynamically zoom charts out though, so setting the bounds ahead of time like this doesn't work for me. I did manage to figure out a way to do this by overriding the axis zoom method though (posting it as an answer momentarily).